# How can I do AMDGPU-PRO Overclock on CentOS / Linux ..?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, amd-radeon, overclocking

I'm Looking for how to overclock RX470 / RX580 AMD grahpic card on CentOS7 or Ubuntu..

I just successed to modify fan attribute but, I couldn't do memory / core clock / voltage..

And I don't know how to show AMD graphic cards state on CentOs

RX series doesn't meet aticonfig config command so i don't what to do ..

these graphics are working on well , But I don't know what can i do to overclock these graphic cards...

I installed amdgpu-pro 17.30 driver on Centos7 and It works well..

Is there anybody who knows overclock AMDGPU-PRO RX* graphic card??

Plz Help me..

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 0):

All commands must be run as root, if you have integrated graphics and/or multiple GPUs your card number (i.e. `card1`, `card2`, …) will vary:

- `cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_dpm_mclk` - list memory states:clocks
- `cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_dpm_sclk` - list gpu states:clocks
- `echo 5 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od` - increase core clock by 5%
- `echo 7 > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_mclk_od` - increase memory clock by 7%